# jQuery onclick and change image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple jQuery that when an image is clicked, it changes to the next image. I got most of it working, but when the last image is clicked, it ends. I would like it to rotate again to the first image so it continues to rotate indefinitely when clicked.

```
<li id="t_01">
    <img src="images/tear_sheets/t_02.jpg" alt="" class="image"/>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zLk430dm/

Comment: Your JS fiddle doesn't show such progress as you've mentioned ("I got most of it working, but when the last image is clicked, it ends")

Comment: But this jsfiddle is not working, it just removes the images.

Comment: You've multiple elements with same id, which is invalid...

Comment: You should provide a clear concept of what should be done and where the problem exactly is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just insert **first li** after **last li**

```
$("img").click(function () {
    $('#tear_sheets li:first').insertAfter($('#tear_sheets li:last'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8ky8wmb8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(".box li").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
        $(".box li:first-child").addClass("active").nextAll("li").removeClass("active")
    } else {
        $(this).next("li").addClass("active").prevAll("li").removeClass("active");
    }
})
```

```css
ul
{
 height: 150px;
 position: relative;
 width: 150px;
}

ul li
{
 left: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: absolute;
 text-decoration: none;
 top: 0;
}

ul li
{
 display: none;
}

ul li.active
{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tear_sheets">
    <h2>Tear Sheets</h2>
    <ul class="box">
        <li id="t_01" class="active">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/175/300" class="image" /></li>
        <li id="t_01">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/300" alt="" class="image" /></li>
        <li id="t_01">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/275/300" alt="" class="image" /></li>
        <li id="t_01">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/190/300" alt="" class="image" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Update (see Comment) Opacity and transition

```js
$(".box li").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
        $(".box li:first-child").addClass("active").nextAll("li").removeClass("active")
    } else {
        $(this).next("li").addClass("active").prevAll("li").removeClass("active");
    }
})
```

```css
ul
{
 height: 150px;
 position: relative;
 width: 150px;
}

ul li
{
 left: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: absolute;
 text-decoration: none;
 top: 0;
}

ul li
{
 opacity:0;
    z-index:-9999;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

ul li.active
{
 opacity:1;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tear_sheets">
    <h2>Tear Sheets</h2>
    <ul class="box">
        <li id="t_01" class="active">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/175/300" class="image" /></li>
        <li id="t_01">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/300" alt="" class="image" /></li>
        <li id="t_01">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/275/300" alt="" class="image" /></li>
        <li id="t_01">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/190/300" alt="" class="image" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

DEMO using fadeIn

```js
$(".box li").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
        $(".box li:first-child").fadeIn("slow").nextAll("li").hide()
    } else {
        $(this).next("li").fadeIn("slow").prevAll("li").hide();
    }
})
```

```css
ul
{
 height: 150px;
 position: relative;
 width: 150px;
}

ul li
{
 left: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: absolute;
 text-decoration: none;
 top: 0;
}

ul li
{
 display: none;
}

ul li.active
{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tear_sheets">
    <h2>Tear Sheets</h2>
    <ul class="box">
        <li id="t_01" class="active">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/175/300" class="image" /></li>
        <li id="t_01">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/300" alt="" class="image" /></li>
        <li id="t_01">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/275/300" alt="" class="image" /></li>
        <li id="t_01">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/190/300" alt="" class="image" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a fadeIn? I added it after .next("li") and it worked until the last image where one image overlapped another.

Comment: Yes you can replace `addClass("active")` width `fadeIn()` and `.removeClass("active")` width `hide()`. Or just play around with the opacity check the update.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the one that you are trying to achieve:

> 1. HTML:

```
    <div id="tear_sheets">
        <h2>Tear Sheets</h2>
        <ul class="box">
        <li id="t_01">  
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/175/300" class="image"/>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/300" alt="" class="image"/>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/275/300" alt="" class="image"/>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/190/300" alt="" class="image"/>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

> ```
> 2. Javascript:
> ```

```
$(function(){
  $("img").hide();
  $("img").first().show();
});

$("img").click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
   debugger;
    if( $(this).next().length === 0) {
          $("img").first().show();
    }
    else {
         $(this).next().show();
    }


})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zLk430dm/1/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with one line script by keep on appending the clicked item to the parent while displaying only the first item:

```js
$("img").click(function () {
    $(this).parent("li").appendTo(".box")
})
```

```css
ul li {
    display:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li:first-child {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tear_sheets">
     <h2>Tear Sheets</h2>

    <ul class="box">
        <li>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/175/300" class="image" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/300" alt="" class="image" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/275/300" alt="" class="image" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/190/300" alt="" class="image" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```